# Subquery Where Something is not assigned

Tags: sql

Still new to SQL.

I am attempting to create a subquery that will return sales people from the salesperson table that are not assigned to any stores on the store table. To do this would I use a NULL to return where a sales person is not assigned to a store ?

Like WHERE SalesPerson = NULL?

Comment: `where SalesPerson is null`.

Comment: Thank you! I assumed this was so, just didn’t know if I  as missing anything!

Answer (score 0):

NULL needs its own kind of logical operator:

```
WHERE SalesPerson IS NULL
```